Powershell Set-VMFirmware syntax error - do I need a different version of Powershell?
I am using Windows 11 Pro, and Powershell version 5.1
I am following this wiki to setup a VM  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/step-by-step-how-to-create-a-windows-11-vm-on-hyper-v-via/ba-p/3754100
But I encounter an error when I run this Line :
Set-VMFirmware -BootOrder "PCVM" -VMName "PCVM"
Set-VMFirmware : Cannot bind parameter 'BootOrder'. Cannot convert the "PCVM" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMComponentObject".
Do I need to upgrade to PowerShell 7?

That article is a little misleading since it's not looking for an input of type [string], but rather a [VMComponentObject] which, I would assume, is referring to a component of the VM or the VM itself.

I stand corrected, see the official docs. And I quote, "The boot order determines the order of the devices from which to boot. The acceptable values for this parameter are: VMBootSource, VMNetworkAdapter, HardDiskDrive, and DVDDrive", with an example of Set-VMFirmware "Test VM" -BootOrder $vmNetworkAdapter, $vmHardDiskDrive

I tried that , but got a different error :  Set-VMFirmware : The specified device is not a valid boot device. I tried this instead :
Set-VMFirmware -VMName "PCVM" -FirstBootDevice $(Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName "PCVM")
but now I hit a error with no finding the OS.
